# Command to remove binding from IIS

Tags: iis, command, command-prompt

In IIS if i want to remove a binding information, we can go to IIS then right click the required site and click edit bindings. Then select the required row from edit site binding popup and click remove button. The same thing i need a command to perform the same operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this command to remove binding from IIS.

```
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.applicationHost/sites /-"[name='Mysite'].bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:80:example.se']" /commit:apphost
```